# Unzipped files mystery location?

Tags: terminal, finder, zip

I used the Terminal to unzip a file by typing Unzip then dragging the file to terminal. The file unzipped successfully and a few GBs were used from my SDD. However, I have no idea where the files are !!! I can't find them in the same folder of the zip file. 
Where would they be ?

Comment: Also try looking in ~/Documents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe in your Home folder? It's the default folder the terminal points to. Try to open it through the Go menu in the finder.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, search for the files name. If it shows up, press or long press (click or right click) the file. Hopefully you'll be able to see the file storage path.